# Associations and class names

Tags: extjs, extjs4, associations, extjs4.2, classname

I tried to build a very simple application that creates a store based on two associated models. (It is based on an example you can find [here](https://github.com/loiane/curso-extjs4/blob/master/aula14/index.html).) This works if I use a shore class name. However, it does not work anymore as soon as I use the class name with the path and the application name, as I was used to do.

I made the following changes:

- Changed "Pessoa" to "Aap.model.Pessoa"
- Changed "Endereco" to "Aap.model.Endereco"

Could somebody please explain to me:

1. What is the underlying problem?
2. What do I have to change in order to make the assosiations work in the second example

---

**Example that works**

app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true, // Allows dynamc loading of JavaSCript files
    disableCaching: false // Disable random parameter in the URLs path}); 

Ext.application({
    name: 'Aap',
    models: ['Pessoa', 'Endereco']});
```

app/model/Pessoa.js:

```
Ext.define('Pessoa', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'nome', type: 'string'}
],
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'data/data',
    format: 'json'
},  
          hasOne: {model: 'Endereco', foreignKey: 'pessoaId'} }
```

app/model/Endereco.js:

```
Ext.define('Endereco', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
    {name: 'logradouro', type: 'string'}
]});
```

data/data.json:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Loiane",
    "sobrenome": "Groner",
    "endereco": {
        "id": 14,
        "logradouro": "rua ficticia",
        "numero": "100"
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Tom",
    "sobrenome": "Stock",
    "endereco": {
        "id": 34,
        "logradouro": "reality street",
        "numero": "55"
    }
}]
```

Command in the browser console:

```
   pessoaStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
model: 'Pessoa'
});
```

As a result I get a store with two properly associated model. If I change the class name, however, association does not work anymore.

---

**Example that does not work**

app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true, // Allows dynamc loading of JavaSCript files
    disableCaching: false // Disable random parameter in the URLs path}); 

Ext.application({
    name: 'Aap',
    models: ['Aap.model.Pessoa', 'Aap.model.Endereco']});
```

app/model/Pessoa.js:

```
Ext.define('Aap.model.Pessoa', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'nome', type: 'string'}
],
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'data/data',
    format: 'json'
},  
          hasOne: {model: 'Aap.model.Endereco', foreignKey: 'pessoaId'} }
```

app/model/Endereco.js:

```
Ext.define('Aap.model.Endereco', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
    {name: 'logradouro', type: 'string'}
]});
```

data/data.json:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Loiane",
    "sobrenome": "Groner",
    "endereco": {
        "id": 14,
        "logradouro": "rua ficticia",
        "numero": "100"
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Tom",
    "sobrenome": "Stock",
    "endereco": {
        "id": 34,
        "logradouro": "reality street",
        "numero": "55"
    }
}]
```

Command in the browser console:

```
pessoaStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'Aap.model.Pessoa'
});
```

Here I get as a result the store with the data of the "Pessoa" model, but the "Endereco" model is not associated and I cannot get the corresponing data.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

In the "app/model/Pessoa.js file" I simply had to replace

```
hasOne: {model: 'Endereco', foreignKey: 'pessoaId'}
```

to

```
hasOne: {model: 'Aap.model.Endereco', associationKey: 'endereco', foreignKey: 'pessoaId'}
```

Now, the associaiton is working correctly.

The **problem the associationKey**, which is the property to read the association from. As explained in the [ExtJS dcumentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association-cfg-associationKey) the associationKey is by default the name of the associated moel.

In the **first example** (the one that worked), this worked well. The associationKey was correspondinly to the model name "*Endereco*" set to "*endereco*" by default.

In the **second example** (the one that did not work), however, the default associationKey did not find any property in the data (app/model/Pessoa.js) with the same name.  The associationKey was correspondinly to the model name "*Aap.model.Endereco*" set to "*aap.model.endereco*" by default.

The associationKey had therefore to be defined explicitely as "*endereco*" in order to solve the problem.